# How to setup phone Volumes on iOS? The volume of media, phone call, etc.. are different

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to control volumes of iPhone. (The volume of media and phone call are not same.)
I'v searched a lot. All of them are just told me use [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview?language=objc) to control volume. I got an information that using MPVolumeView is one way and it can't setup multi-volume one time. But it's old(2014). So, I'm not sure is any new idea for this.

I'v tried to setup different volume. The first one is media volume. The other is Phone call volume. They are not same. I exactly there are two volumes on iOS.

[image: Youtube volume]

[image: Phone call volume]

Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks!